# Где ставить запятые: "Тише тише тебе сейчас нельзя разговаривать"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> Тише тише тебе сейчас нельзя разговаривать.

Answer (score 3):

Пунктуация в предложении во многом зависит от контекста (ситуации, обстановки), в котором эти слова произносятся, и может быть вариативной.
Cтрах, боль, напряженность, безысходность, растерянность или, наоборот, настойчивость — эти чувства напрямую влияют на пунктуацию.
Вот некоторые примеры.

*— Тише, тише, тебе сейчас нельзя много говорить. Хорошо?

Софи утвердительно кивнула и прикрыла глаза.*
В. Воронин. Ковчег царя Айя

*— Тише, милый, тише! Ты же знаешь, что тебе нельзя разговаривать! Ты очень, очень болен!*
М. Твен. Приключения Тома Сойера

*— Тише, тише... – попросила Настя и коснулась её губ мокрым полотенцем. – Молчи, тебе нельзя говорить.*
О. Ласовская. Амулет

*— Тише, тише. Мне сказали, что тебе нельзя громко разговаривать!*
Е. Теущакова. 365 дней лета

Comment: @Сибиряк Я отклонила Вашу правку. При своей правке я видела, что нет точки в конце предложения, но оставила "как есть" (стараюсь авторские предложения не менять). Возможно, автор хотел знать **какие вообще** здесь могут стоять знаки. Тогда шапку можно переформулировать так: Какие знаки препинания требуются (необходимы)? Есть разница? Действуйте. Поддержу.

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант (наиболее, на мой взгляд, соответствующий той интонации, с какой эти слова могли бы быть произнесены):

***Тише, тише... Тебе сейчас нельзя разговаривать.***

Comment: Спасибо, slava1947